# Radial and transverse velocity

Tags: aerospace-engineering, kinematics

> A comet at its point of closest approach to the sun where the radial
> distance from the centre of the sun is $50\times10^6$ miles, has a
> velocity of 188,500 ft/sec. Determine the radial and transverse
> components of its velocity at a point B, where the radial distance
> from the centroid of the sun is $75\times10^6$ miles.

I've managed to determine that the comet will have a velocity of 23.80 mi/s at point B, but can someone explain how I would get the radial and transverse components of this? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: What principle / logic did you use to get `23.80 mi/s` ?

Comment: Inverse square potential fields have a hypersymmetry associated with them that introduces an extra conservative function. The one you are interested in is called the [Laplace-Runge-Lentz vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace%E2%80%93Runge%E2%80%93Lenz_vector).

Comment: The comet is not orbiting around the sun, without knowing the internal angle between the lines (from the sun to the points), there is no solution.

Answer (score 2):

You could calculate the velocity magnitude from total energy ([gravitational](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_energy) and kinetic) of the comet, which must be constant:
$$E = E_p+E_k = -\frac{G\cdot M\cdot m}{r_A}+\frac{1}{2}m\cdot v_A^2 = -\frac{G\cdot M\cdot m}{r_B}+\frac{1}{2}m\cdot v_B^2$$
From that, the velocity magnitude $v_B$ at point B is:
$$v_B = \sqrt{v_A^2-2\cdot G\cdot M\cdot \frac{r_B-r_A}{r_A\cdot r_B}}$$
(You will need gravitational constant $G$ and mass of the Sun $M$.)

For the velocity components, you can use [second Keplers law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kepler%27s_laws_of_planetary_motion#Second_law), which states that area velocity $\vec{A}$ is constant:
$$\vec{A} = \vec{r}_A \times \vec{v}_A = \vec{r}_B \times \vec{v}_B$$
From that, area velocity magnitude can be expressed as:
$$A = r_A\cdot v_A \cdot \sin(\alpha) = r_B\cdot v_B \cdot \sin(\beta)$$
Since $\alpha$ is 90°, the angle $\beta$ between [position vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Position_(geometry)) $\vec{r}_B$ and velocity vector $\vec{v}_B$ will be:
$$\beta = \arcsin\left(\frac{r_A\cdot v_A}{r_B\cdot v_B}\right)$$
Now the radial and transverse velocity components at point B are:
$$\vec{v}_B = \left(v_B\cdot \cos(\beta), v_B\cdot \sin(\beta)\right)$$

(Technically there are two points B, so this is only one of the two solutions, but I think you can easily work out the second one if needed.)

Comment: Good argument.  Two comments.  Firstly, the reason we know that $\alpha$ is a right angle is that "closest approach" means an extremum of radial distance, so the radial component of velocity there must be zero.  Secondly, Kepler's second law is just a prettyfied geometric way of (p)restating conservation of angular momentum.